# Configurable location of keystore in WSS4J

Tags: java, wss4j

I have a spring context that initializes CXF web service and wraps it with signature checking:

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:my.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="properties" ref="myProperties"/>
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="!sp{"/>
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="inbound-security" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="!sp{acq.signature.properties.location}"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I realized that `signaturePropFile` must be on classpath, it cannot be read from filesystem :-(

```
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Cannot load the resource D:\Dev\Projekty\smartpos-backend-parent\smartpos-backend-acquirer\src\main\resources\signature.properties)
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getProperties(CryptoFactory.java:261) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:186) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.java:224) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:911) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
```

Nevermind, I let it be part of deployment, but I do want to externalize keystore, which is defined with following property:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=server-keystore.jks
```

I tried to replace the path with some configuration property `!sp{keystore.location}` and `${keystore.location}`, but it does not work. In fact it fails with same exception like property file does not exist:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Cannot load the resource classpath:signature.properties)
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getProperties(CryptoFactory.java:261) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:186) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(AbstractWSS4JInterceptor.java:224) ~[cxf-rt-ws-security-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.loadCrypto(WSHandler.java:911) ~[wss4j-1.6.11.jar:1.6.11]
```

What is a proper way to configure WSS4J keystore location? I do not like editing war before deployment. (I use maven to build it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been [solved lately](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-540).

When using the older version of the wss4j (v2.1.1 and older) you can pass the need of the String reference for the property file (e.g. WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_REF_ID) by overriding WSHandler.loadCrypto() and injecting a created Property object by Spring util, e.g.:

```
<util:properties id="wss4jCryptoProperties">
    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file">!sp{keystore.file}</prop>
    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">!sp{keystore.type}</prop>
    <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">!sp{keystore.password}</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Overriding the WSHandler.loadCrypto() by an example:

```
public class PropertiesWSS4JInInterceptor extends WSS4JInInterceptor {

    private Properties cryptoProperties;

    public PropertiesWSS4JInInterceptor(Map<String, Object> inProps,
                                        Properties cryptoProperties) {
        super(inProps);
        this.cryptoProperties = cryptoProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected Crypto loadCrypto(String cryptoPropertyFile, String cryptoPropertyRefId,
                                RequestData requestData) throws WSSecurityException {
        return CryptoFactory.getInstance(cryptoProperties);
    }
}
```

In addition, you can inject the wss4jCryptoProperties in your customBean (don't forget to create the field named cryptoProperties in the referenced class and a setter):

```
<bean id="customBean" class="cz.company.CustomBean">
    <property name="cryptoProperties" ref="wss4jCryptoProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Finally, you can add the interceptor to your endpoint:

```
endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new PropertiesWSS4JInInterceptor(inProps, cryptoProperties));
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that it will help but I had a similar goal: I wanted to point to a keystore outside my jar because it depends on the final user certificate.

Providing that your Manifest.mf has this classpath setup:

**Class-Path: .**

You can simply target an external folder in the same directory than your jar. In my case, I do the following:

**org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=config-folder/mycert.jks**

Being **config-folder** in the same directory that my **application.jar** file.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this page to resolve my problem of referring it from external folder. 
actually while converting the path of property  *org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file * , It is being fed to FileSystem. File(path) -

> Merlin.java:333

could actually decrypt the path of the file from external folder. No need to do extra work.

*org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=/usr/local/path/server-keystore.jks*
works!!!